# boostrap-vue how to access ordered/filtered row data

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am successfully using b-table component from Boostrap-vue library, but now I need to make a further step which I can't figure out.

Once the user has ordered and/or filtered the rows within the table, I need to extract the first 10 (or 20, or whatever number) rows to show them in a map, as each row contains an address.

If I access the original items' array, rows are not filtered nor ordered, of course.

Now, both filtering and ordering are done via built-in filtering and ordering processes, so maybe, I can change to customized ones and inside those methods, the very first -n- rows may be added to an array.

Does it sound unfeasible? Are there other tricks I haven't think about yet? I would like to hear how you solved or afford this task.

Thank you

I am not sure code can help in this case, because I am actively looking for a solution, as I don't have any. Anyway, this is how I defined my table.

```js
              <b-table
                :busy="isBusy"
                :items="listaContatti"
                :fields="fields"
                :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
                :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
                :filter="filter"
                :filterIncludedFields="filterOn"
                :filterIgnoredFields="filterOmit"
                id="contatti"
                primary-key="codice"
                ref="selectableTable"
                selectable
                select-mode="single"
                empty-text="Non trovati contatti"
                empty-filtered-text="Nessun contatto risponde ai criteri di ricerca"
                show-empty
                responsive
                borderless
                foot-clone
                hover
                outlined
                small
                striped
                head-variant="dark"
                table-class="table-vcenter"
                sticky-header="1000px"
                class="font-size-sm"
                @filtered="onFiltered"
                @row-selected="onRowSelected"
              >
                <!-- Busy table -->
                <template v-slot:table-busy>
                  <div class="text-center text-danger my-2">
                    <b-spinner class="align-middle"></b-spinner>
                    <strong>Caricamento...</strong>
                  </div>
                </template>

                <!-- Empty table -->
                <template v-slot:empty="scope" :show-empty="isEmpty">
                  <h4>{{ scope.emptyText }}</h4>
                </template>

                <!-- No rows selected -->
                <template v-slot:emptyfiltered="scope">
                  <h4>{{ scope.emptyFilteredText }}</h4>
                </template>

                <!-- Index -->
                <template v-slot:cell(index)="row">
                  {{ row.index + 1 }}
                </template>

                <!-- ATECO -->
                <template v-slot:cell(ateco)="row"> {{ row.item.codiceAteco }} - {{ row.item.desAteco }} </template>

                <!-- Available phone numbers -->
                <template v-slot:cell(telefoni)="row">
                  {{ row.item.attivitaTel1 }}, {{ row.item.attivitaTel2 }}, {{ row.item.cellulare }}
                </template>

                <!-- Contact actions -->
                <template v-slot:cell(actions)="row">
                  <!-- botton example
                  <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails" class="mr-2">
                    {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Nascondi' : 'Vedi' }} Dettagli
                  </b-button> 
                  -->
                  <button
                    type="button"
                    class="btn-block-option"
                    block
                    v-b-tooltip.hover.bottom="'Dettagli'"
                    @click="row.toggleDetails"
                  >
                    <i class="si si-magnifier"></i>
                  </button>
                </template>

                <!-- Contact details -->
                <template v-slot:row-details="row">
                  <b-card>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Ateco:</b></b-col>
                      <b-col>{{ row.item.codiceAteco }} - {{ row.item.desAteco }}</b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Recapiti in azienda:</b></b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(email)</small> {{ row.item.attivitaEmail }}</b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(telefoni)</small> {{ row.item.attivitaTel1 }}, {{ row.item.attivitaTel2 }}</b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(fax)</small> {{ row.item.attivitaFax }}</b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Azienda:</b></b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(forma)</small> {{ row.item.formaGiuridica }}</b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(natura)</small> {{ row.item.natura }}</b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(fatturato)</small> {{ row.item.classeFatturato }}</b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Note:</b></b-col>
                      <b-col>{{ row.item.note }}</b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(dipendenti)</small> {{ row.item.classeDipendenti }}</b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row>
                      <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Ex-sponsor:</b></b-col>
                      <b-col
                        ><span v-if="row.item.exSponsor"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i></span
                      ></b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(iniziativa precedente)</small> {{ row.item.iniziativaPrec }}</b-col>
                      <b-col><small>(data ordine)</small> {{ row.item.dataOrdine }}</b-col>
                    </b-row>
                    <b-row class="mb-1">
                      <b-col sm="3" class="text-sm-right"><b>Sito web:</b></b-col>
                      <b-col>{{ row.item.sitoWeb }}</b-col>
                    </b-row>

                    <!-- <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails">Hide Details</b-button> -->
                  </b-card>
                </template>
              </b-table>
```

and this is data function

```js
  data() {
    return {
      isBusy: true,
      sortBy: '',
      sortDesc: false,
      selectMode: 'multi',
      selected: [],
      filter: null,
      filterOn: [],
      filterOmit: [],
      totalFilteredRows: 0,
      filtriRichiesti: {},
      fields: [
        // { key: 'index', label: 'Seq' },
        { key: 'tipo', thStyle: 'width: 75px;', thClass: 'text-center', tdClass: 'text-center', sortable: true },
        { key: 'codice', sortable: true, label: 'Codice' },
        { key: 'cf', sortable: true, label: 'CF' },
        { key: 'piva', sortable: true, label: 'P.Iva' },
        { key: 'denominazione', sortable: true },
        { key: 'ateco', sortable: true, label: 'ATECO' },
        { key: 'indirizzo', sortable: true },
        { key: 'frazione', sortable: true },
        { key: 'cap', sortable: true, label: 'CAP' },
        { key: 'comune', sortable: true, label: 'Comune' },
        { key: 'provincia', sortable: true, label: 'Pr' },
        { key: 'telefoni', sortable: true, label: 'Rec.telef.' },
        { key: 'ultimoStato', sortable: true, label: 'Stato' },
        { key: 'lat', sortable: true, label: 'Lat' },
        { key: 'long', sortable: true, label: 'Long' },
        { key: 'actions', label: '' }
      ]
    }
  }
```

The items list, listaContatti, comes from the Vuex store where it has been stored after calling a REST API on the server.

Comment: please share some code in codepen

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, I hope--one solution is to use a custom footer. This gives the showOnMap() method access to the *displayed* table records--after filtering, sorting, and pagination:

```
<template v-slot:custom-foot="displayedTable">
  <a @click="showOnMap(displayedTable.items)>Show On Map</a>
</template>
```

Credit where due: [https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/dliwwh/how_do_i_access_the_filtered_data_from_btable_in/]

Bootstrap Vue docs: [https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#creating-a-custom-footer]